# How can I give a Flat Package (.pkg) an icon which is seen on different computers?

Tags: macos, installation, icons, package, packagemaker

I know it's possible to give a .pkg file an icon which is seen on my Mac, but I want to make it so it's seen by everyone who might get this package.

I've seen this before so I know it's possible, but when opening a .pkg which does have an icon set the way I want it I can't see anything which is pointing to an icon so I'm stumped. Apple aren't exactly helpful with this kinda stuff.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The solution here worked for me: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371790/how-to-set-icon-on-file-or-directory-using-cli-on-os-x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Custom icons for files live in the `icns` -16455 resource.  You can simply copy and paste using into the Finder's Info window to set an icon, or you can automate the process of incorporating an `.icns` file using Rez, like this:

```
echo "read 'icns' (-16455) \"foo.icns\";" | Rez -o foo.pkg ; SetFile -a C foo.pkg
```

Note that in newer Xcode revisions, Rez and SetFile are located inside the Xcode bundle in `Contents/Developer/Tools`; you can also locate them with xcrun.

To distribute your flat package with its icon intact, you will need to compress/encode it with a tool that will include its resource fork, such as Apple's tar, CPIO or Zip implementations (the latter two either via Archive Utility or `ditto`), or place it in a disk image.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that I had to be moving it via .zip to keep the icon!

Comment: I am too, now.  My guess is that something broke in OS X 10.7 or 10.8.  You'll need to find another way.